# File (image) does not update

Tags: php, symfony

I made an application with Symfony, and I am using a Media Entity to allow uploading files and linking them with other entities (ex: an image with an article).

If I want to create a new article with a picture everything will work perfectly, but if later I want to change this same picture it wouldn't work. Furthermore if at the same time I update another field, such as title or anything else, I will see them all change except the picture.

Not a single error is returned so I guess this has to be linked with the configuration, but I couldn't find any issues.

My code:
Media.php

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* Media
*
* @ORM\Table("media")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MediaRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
*/
class Media
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\COlumn(name="updated_at",type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $updateAt;

/**
 * @ORM\PostLoad()
 */
public function postLoad()
{
    $this->updateAt = new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255, nullable=true)
 */
public $path;

public $file;

public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return realpath(__dir__.'/../../../web/img/upload');
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getAssetPath()
{
    return 'img/upload/'.$this->path;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    $this->tempFile = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    $this->oldFile = $this->getPath();
    $this->updateAt = new \DateTime();

    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->path = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    $extentions_allowed = array('jpeg', 'png', 'svg', 'gif');

    if (null !== $this->file) {
        if(in_array($this->file->guessExtension(), $extentions_allowed))
        {
            $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);
            unset($this->file);
            if ($this->oldFile != null) unlink($this->tempFile);

        }else {
            unset($this->file);
            throw new \Exception('Seules les images sont autorisées (jpg/png/gif/svg)');
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function preRemoveUpload()
{
    $this->tempFile = $this->getAbsolutePath();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if(file_exists($this->tempFile)){
        unlink($this->tempFile);
    }
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getPath()
{
    return $this->path;
}

}
```

Controller which updates the entity (Article for instance)

```
public function blocAction(Request $request, Bloc $bloc = null){

    if($bloc){
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\BlocType', $bloc, array(
            'type' => $bloc->getType()
        ));
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ){
                try{
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($bloc);
                    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
                }catch (\Exception $e){
                    $this->addFlash(
                        'error',
                        $e->getMessage()
                    );
                }

            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_admin_bloc', array('id' => $bloc->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('admin/bloc.html.twig', array(
            'bloc' => $bloc,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }else{
       return $this->redirectToRoute('app_admin_index');
    }


}
```

The form of the entity

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;


class MediaType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('file',FileType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'image-preview'
            )
        ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Media'
    ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'app_bundle_media';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should clean your Media entity because it mixes public with private properties and it has too much logic. A best practice would be:

- to set all your properties to private and access them via getter/setter methods;
- put your upload logic ideally in a service that does only that.

Then in order for your form to trigger errors you need to add assertions annotations to your entity:
example:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Media
{
    //...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;

     /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\File(
     *     mimeTypes={"image/jpeg", "image/png", "application/svg+xml", "image/gif"},
     *     message="Seules les images sont autorisées (jpg/png/gif/svg)"
     * )
     */
    private $file;

    //...
```

That way you will get rid of your current `$extentions_allowed` check.

Have a look at this detailed doc on how to upload a file properly: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html